# How can I echo session then unset it ?

Tags: php

How can I unset session in PHP , I try to make flash session . I searching some topic that  same as my problem and I found try to put exit(); adfter header:location but it didnt work for me

in my Controller

```
 Session::set('add_message', 'added');
return redirect('/list','',array('detail_id'=>$id));
```

in my redirect function I alredy add exit();

```
function redirect($as, $parameter=array(), $query_string=array()) {
        header('Location: '.route($as, $parameter, $query_string), true, 301);
        exit;
    }
```

in my html I try to echo  session add_message and unset it but it didnt unset

```
if ($_SESSION('add_message')) {
            echo $_SESSION('add_message');
            unset($_SESSION['add_message']);
          }
```

Comment: that's my answer @Mike thankou

Answer (score -1):

```
$_SESSION('add_message') = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

```
session_unset();    // remove all session variables
session_destroy(); // destroy the session
```